# Return results that match random number of dynamic conditions

Tags: php, sql

Firstly, i have an array which im passing through a switch statement, to match a regexp for each value, and then perform a query depending on whether it matches. My problem is that if the array contains 1 or more values that match one of the regexp's i want the query that is defined to filter the results from any past or future query's performed for that array,i was thinking about the INTERSECT SQL command but cant think how that would be implemented since i don't know how many cases will be matched, and i don't want to add loads of if/else statements.

Here's an example of my code so far:

```
$dataArray = explode(',', $data)
$query = mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ? Like ?")
foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
    switch ($value) {
        case preg_match('/(^abcd)/', $value):
            $query->bind_param("ss", $var1, $var2);
            break;

... More cases ...

        default:
            $query = bind_param("ss", $var3, $var4);;
            break;
    };
```

Comment: maybe you can used UNION statement in case of more than 1 value match

Comment: no that will list all that matches in both i need it to filter the results so only ones that match both queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can `prepare` query for such requirement. You would have to generate ad-hoc query (or at least its `WHERE` part).

Like:

```
$conditions = array();

foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value)
{
    if (preg_match('/(^abcd)/', $value))
    {
        $conditions[] = "$var1 LIKE $var2";
    }

    if (preg_match('/(^efgh)/', $value))
    {
        $conditions[] = "$var3 LIKE $var4";
    }

    ...
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $conditions);
```

I'm not sure of you allow one `$value` to match multiple patterns or not. Also I do not know, if you want to use `$key` for something.

Comment: each $value can only be matched once, and at the moment $key is not being used or though it may be in the future.and thank you for this answer i see no reason why it wouldn't work i will implement it and check it works